# how to send attached via email using SES and lambda in Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am trying to send the files stored in s3 via email using AWS SES and lambda in java. Mail has send successfully but when i am trying to open the file getting error "Excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Code Snippet in java :
public class EmailNotification {

```
static LambdaLogger logger = null;
private static String SENDER=null;
private static String RECIPIENT=null;
private static String SUBJECT=null;
private static String BODY_TEXT=null;
private static String filekey=null;

public void verifyEmailNotification(Context context) throws Exception {
    LambdaLogger logger = null;
    
    try {
        logger = context.getLogger();
        String bucket_name = "bucket_name";
        String key_name = "path/";
        String file_name ="file_name.xlsx";
        filekey = key_name + file_name;
        AmazonS3 s3client = GetAWSClients.getS3();
        boolean isFileExists=Utility.checkIfFileExists(bucket_name, filekey);
        logger.log("isFileExists " + isFileExists);
        if (isFileExists)
            filekey = key_name + file_name;
        else
            logger.log("file not available");
        
        InputStream stream = s3client.getObject(bucket_name, filekey).getObjectContent();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(bos);
        ByteArrayInputStream contentsAsStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();
        
        md.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        md.setSSEAlgorithm(ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);
        md.setContentLength(bos.toByteArray().length);
        
        SENDER = "sender email";
        RECIPIENT = "receiver email";
        SUBJECT = "subject";
        BODY_TEXT = "Body text";
        
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSubject(SUBJECT);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SENDER));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(RECIPIENT));
        MimeMultipart msg_body = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textPart.setContent(BODY_TEXT, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        msg_body.addBodyPart(textPart);
        
        MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bos.toByteArray(), "application/octet-stream");
        att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        att.setFileName(TemplateFile);
        message.setContent(msg_body);
        msg_body.addBodyPart(att);
        
        
        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES "
                              +"using the AWS SDK for Java...");
            AmazonSimpleEmailService client = GetAWSClients.getSES();
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            message.writeTo(outputStream);
            RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));
            SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
            client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
            System.out.println("Email sent!");
            workbook.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Email Failed");
            System.err.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Email Failed");
        System.err.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your Question to show us your code where the error is occurring. Also, please note that S3 paths normally look like: `s3://bucket-name/path/file_name.xlsx`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code there, rather than putting it in comments. Also, let us know which line is generating the error.

Comment: Sure @JohnRotenstein

Comment: I am able to send the email with attachment but when i am trying to open the file getting error.. file extension has changed or file has corrupted something.

Answer (score 0):

Used POI and workbooks concept and resolved the issue.

```
public void verifyEmailNotification(Context context) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        String bucketName = "bucketName";
        String key = "prefix";
        String fileName = "fileName.xlsx";
        String keyName = key + fileName;
        S3Object fullObject = null;
        try {
            SENDER = "sender email";
            RECIPIENT = "receiver email";
            SUBJECT = "Subject msg";
            BODY_TEXT = "Hi";
                    
            logger = context.getLogger();

            AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
            InputStream stream = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName)).getObjectContent();

            // Preparing input-stream as spreed sheet.
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            workbook.write(bos);

            logger.log("Read success\n");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setSubject(SUBJECT);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SENDER));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(RECIPIENT));

            MimeMultipart msg_body = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
            MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            textPart.setContent(BODY_TEXT, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
            msg_body.addBodyPart(textPart);

            // Preparing the attachment from the spread sheet
            MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bos.toByteArray(), "application/octet-stream");
            att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            att.setFileName(fileName);
            msg_body.addBodyPart(att);
            message.setContent(msg_body);

            logger.log("attachment prepared\n");

            AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
            AmazonSimpleEmailService client = GetAWSClients.getSES();
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            message.writeTo(outputStream);
            RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));
            SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
            client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
            System.out.println("Email sent!");

        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```